# PHPmyadmin still giving Error Afert Re installing LAMPP severals times

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, lampp

For any reason I getting this error.

[image: This is from my localhost http://localhost/phpmyadmin/]

I reinstalled LAMPP but doesn't help, Searching in the web I found that I should change the configuration file where my credential are.

This is my file configuration config.inc.php (phpmyadmin)

```
  <?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/**
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/**
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/**
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

/**
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/**
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/**
 * Whether to display icons or text or both icons and text in table row
 * action segment. Value can be either of 'icons', 'text' or 'both'.
 * default = 'both'
 */
//$cfg['RowActionType'] = 'icons';

/**
 * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
 * button in browse mode or not.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

/**
 * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
 * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
 * Possible values: 25, 50, 100, 250, 500
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

/**
 * Disallow editing of binary fields
 * valid values are:
 *   false    allow editing
 *   'blob'   allow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'noblob' disallow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'all'    disallow editing
 * default = 'blob'
 */
//$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = false;

/**
 * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
 * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
 * uncomment the desired line:
 * default = 'en'
 */
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

/**
 * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
 * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
 * default = 1
 */
//$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

/**
 * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
 * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
 *
 * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

/**
 * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

/**
 * Whether or not to query the user before sending the error report to
 * the phpMyAdmin team when a JavaScript error occurs
 *
 * Available options
 * ('ask' | 'always' | 'never')
 * default = 'ask'
 */
//$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'always';

/**
 * You can find more configuration options in the documentation
 * in the doc/ folder or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 */
```

I don't remember been changed the credentials, and if I did, Why after reinstalled LAMPP doesn't work?

I'm using Debian 8, with LAMPP.

It's possible that exist another credential in my OS which overwrite the LAMPP credentials?

How Can I fix this?

Thanks a lot, If you need more information, please let me know.

**Update 1:**
I did stop the LAMPP completely and restarted my pc, and verified that LAMPP is not working.
I searched in my process something reference to mysql and I get this:

```
ps aux |grep mysql
root       973  0.0  0.0   4336  1584 ?        S    21:14   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql     1326  0.1  0.5 492624 46672 ?        Sl   21:14   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306

sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                                           4.028-2+deb8u2                       amd64        Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysqlclient-dev                                          5.5.54-0+deb8u1                      amd64        MySQL database development files
ii  libmysqlclient18:amd64                                      5.5.54-0+deb8u1                      amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64                                      4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 amd64        Qt 4 MySQL database driver
ii  mysql-client                                                5.5.54-0+deb8u1                      all          MySQL database client (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-client-5.5                                            5.5.54-0+deb8u1                      amd64        MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-common                                                5.5.54-0+deb8u1                      all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  mysql-server                                                5.5.54-0+deb8u1                      all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-server-5.5                                            5.5.54-0+deb8u1                      amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-5.5                                       5.5.54-0+deb8u1                      amd64        MySQL database server binaries
ii  python-mysqldb                                              1.2.3-2.1                            amd64        Python interface to MySQL
```

So @Naincy you was right in your thinking, something else is starting my MySql.

Comment: plenty of resolutions online....search

Comment: uninstall phpmyadmin and reinstall...
before that please check you have mysql installed or not

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in order to bypass this error message and get in to MySQL, you can edit your `config.inc.php` and temporarily comment out the lines for controluser, controlpass, and maybe also pmadb. I wouldn't do that, though, because of your two conflicting MySQL servers.

As you've determined, you have MySQL installed through apt *and* through LAMPP, which will cause all kinds of difficulties, plus they probably are conflicting by both trying to start on port 3306. If you have valuable data, you should export it then I recommend removing the Debian-packaged one because you're using the whole LAMPP stack which is meant to work together. Then you can start the LAMPP MySQL and try to connect from phpMyAdmin, I imagine it will go better for you.